# Two questions of TradeStation charts

Tags: charts, stock, trading, tradestation

I am evaluating which one to choose, TWS from IB or TS. TWS has a demo account but TS does not. I have two questions about TS stock chart.

1. premarket data in charts start from 4am, or later? TWS starts from 4am. I know TS only allows trades after 8am. I am just wondering if premarket data in chart also starts late.
2. when premarket data is displayed along with regular trading hour data,  HOURLY candle is aligned with 9am or 9:30am? TWS has hourly candle aligned with 9am not market opening time. I honestly don't like it. I am just wondering if TS does the same thing.

If anyone can answer me these two questions, I would be really appreciated!

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set when you want TS to show you data from, in terms of sessions; if it's there, they'll find it. So yes, I can for example set my TS chart to show 'premarket' AAPL data from 0300 (or really any other time). I can't trade it before the exchange opens though, as that would be an OTC/ off-exchange trade which you have to be an institution to do.
2. Candles are aligned with 0930, but that doesn't matter; it can be changed in settings, also though when backtesting, you should use LIBB (Look Intra Bar).

Hope this helps! I strongly recommend you take a close look at MultiCharts too, using IQFeed data.

Also remember, all these systems are buggy as all hell. Managing workflow with them is as much about learning and overcoming their eccentricities, as it is doing the work.